# how to get UUID of phone in php?

Tags: javascript, php

i want to get any UUID of phone to know if  the user visited webpage whether using browser or my android app. I want to know how using php.

I have tried many things like getting a mac address of device but it leads me nowhere not able to get the mac address.

Code used to get the MAC is

```
<?php 

$ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$macAddr=false;

#run the external command, break output into lines
$arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
$lines=explode("\n", $arp);

#look for the output line describing our IP address
foreach($lines as $line)
{
   $cols=preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
   if ($cols[0]==$ipAddress)
   {
       $macAddr=$cols[1];
   }
}

echo $macAddr;


?>
```

but this gives me same for every device.

help me to get any UUID using php.

Thank you.

Comment: `but this gives me same for every device` - it would, because php is a server side scripting "language" - and you can't get the MAC address of the client side in the browser thankfully

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your reply. can you give me any other way of finding uniqueness (UUID) of phone.

Comment: No because I value my privacy and don't wish to help anyone uniquely tag my phone that can't do it themselves

Comment: @JaromandaX ok then how would i know if the user has already visited this page or not. because the user can visit it from application and from browser. I have done the application part but facing issue when it comes to browser.

Comment: I guess that is a problem - cheer up, someone may come along and show you eventually

Comment: If you were able to uniquely identify phones, do you know what implications would be, besides making your job easy? Not a single sane person would use phones or anything else for that matter that delivered **unique** identification of the device (well, at least I wouldn't, I'm aware that majority of population are pure idiots). Bottom line - you **can't** get it and most of all - you **shouldn't**.

Comment: try this github link may be it can help : https://github.com/biggora/device-uuid

Answer (score 1):

There is no way.  Phones don't send a UUID or other unique identifier over the web to PHP (or any other web) applications and the MAC address won't necessarily be reliable (assuming you can get it at all) since the MAC address may change behind NAT firewalls (wifi) or other networking hardware on the cellular networks.

The best you could do would be to try to [fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) the device based on things like user agent, plugins, screen size etc.